# ayuda en php tengo este error

Tags: php, javascript, web

es para iniciar sesion en unpanel de admin de una app web

> Notice: Undefined index: RESQUEST_METHOD in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\grupos\proyectpudines jhon , erbin ,, jordy\login.php
>   on line 4

```
<?php 
// archivo del admin 
require 'config.php';
require '../functions.php';

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);
// comprobar session 
if (!$conexion){
    header ('location: ../error.php');
}

$posts = obtener_post ($blog_config['post_por_pagina'], $conexion);
require '../views/admin_index.view.php';


?>
```

<-- archivo config -->

```
<?php

define('RUTA', 'http://localhost/grupos/proyectpudines jhon , erbin ,, jordy');


$bd_config = array(
    'basedatos' => 'amiscake',
    'usuario' => 'root',
    'pass' => ''
);


$blog_config = array(
    'post_por_pagina' => '8',
    'carpeta_imagenes' => 'imagenes/'
);

$blog_admin = array(
    'usuario' => 'jhon',
    'password' => '123'
);
?>
```

<-- archivo functions -->

```
<?php

// CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
function conexion($bd_config){
try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['basedatos'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['pass']);
    return $conexion;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
    }
}

// FUNCION PARA QUE EL USUARIO NO ME INYECTE CODIGO
function limpiardatos($datos){
    $datos = trim($datos);
    $datos = stripcslashes($datos);
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
    return $datos;

}

// FUNCION PARA MOSTRAR POR PAGINA
function pagina_actual(){
    return isset($_GET['p']) ? (int)$_GET['p'] : 1;
}

// LA FUNCION QUE ME OBTIENE LOS POST DE LA BASE DE DATOS
function obtener_post($post_por_pagina, $conexion){
      $inicio = (pagina_actual() > 1 ) ? pagina_actual() * $post_por_pagina - $post_por_pagina: 0;
      $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM articulosamiscake LIMIT $inicio, $post_por_pagina ");
      $sentencia->execute();
      return $sentencia->fetchAll();
}

function numero_paginas($post_por_pagina, $conexion){
    $total_post = $conexion->prepare('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total ');
    $total_post->execute();
    $total_post = $total_post->fetch()['total'];
    $numero_paginas = ceil($total_post / $post_por_pagina);
    return $numero_paginas;

}

function id_articulo($id){
    return (int)limpiardatos($id);
}

function obtener_post_por_id($conexion, $id){
    $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM articulosamiscake WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1");
    $resultado = $resultado->fetchAll();
    return($resultado) ? $resultado : false;

}


function fecha ($fecha){
    $timestamp = strtotime($fecha);
    $meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

    $dia = date('d', $timestamp);
    $mes = date('m', $timestamp) - 1;
    $year = date('Y', $timestamp);
    $fecha = " $dia  " . $meses[$mes] ."  $year";
    return $fecha;
}

?>
```

Comment: necesitamos ver los 2 archivos de arriba!

Comment: listo  ya los añadi

Comment: está correcto que la constante RUTA del archivo config tenga sólo las comas vacías entre erbin y jordy??

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Cuál de todos es el archivo `login.php` y cuál es la línea 4 de ese archivo? Es evidente que tienes un problema con tu constante `RUTA` (no tiene sentido definir una constante así como la tienes definida), pero no parece que la uses en ninguna parte del código que has compartido. ¿Para qué es esa constante y por qué la defines de esa forma tan extraña?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, el código que muestras no le veo problemas.

Muy probablemente el error está en tu archivo **admin_index.view.php**.

Comentar la línea: `require '../views/admin_index.view.php';` y vuelve a probar o comparte un poco más el código del archivo  **'admin_index.view.php'**.

La definición de la constante está correcta.